# (C#) How to use SQLite WAL mode in Windows CE?

Tags: c#, sqlite

> Windows CE
>   .NET compact framework 3.5
>   SQlite Dll File: sqlite-netFx35-binary-PocketPC-ARM-2008-1.0.105.0.zip

I want to use wal mode. so, I written the below code.

```
string sql = "PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;";   
SQLiteCommand cmd = new  SQLiteCommand(sql, cnn);  
var journalMode = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

But, journalMode was set to 'delete'.

The other setting like 'journal_mode = OFF' is ok.
And when I try to open database file that is set to wal mode, an error occurs.

> "file is encrypted or is not a database file is encrypted or is not
>   a database"

So, I thought that SQL dll version has problem.
because WAL mode is supported after version 3.7.0.
but the version was 3.18.0 when I checked SQLiteConnection.SQLiteVersion.

Also, the SQlite dll file I used was descripted.

> This binary package contains all the binaries for the PocketPC version
>   of the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.105.0 (3.18.0) package. The included
>   native binaries should work on all supported ARM versions of Windows
>   CE prior to Windows Embedded Compact 2013. The .NET Compact Framework
>   3.5 is required.

What is the problem?

Isn't WinCE supported WAL mode?

I really don't Know.